# Chain rule and conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I know 
$$
P(B|A,C) = \frac{P(A,C|B)\cdot P(B)}{P(A,C)}
$$
by Bayes Rule. But how can $P(A, C|B)$ be simplified further?

Will the chain rule for conditional probability also work?

Comment: What do you mean by "chain rule for conditional probability"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, the **simplest** formula for $P(B|A,C)$ is $P(A,B,C)/P(A,C)$. The other expressions are just variations on this one.